# Converting hash-generating code from ASP to PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, converters

I have this code in ASP:

```
Public Function ComputeCredentialHash(ByVal timestamp As DateTime, ByVal id As String, ByVal authKey As String) As String
    Dim sig As String = timestamp.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ") & id & authKey
    Dim sigdata As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sig)
    Dim md5 As System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 = New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim md5Hash As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(sigdata))
    Return md5Hash
End Function
```

And I need to write a PHP function that does the same thing.  So far I have:

```
function ComputeCredentialHash ($timestamp, $id, $authKey) {
    $sigData = mb_convert_encoding($timestamp.$id.$authKey, "ASCII", "auto");
    $md5 = md5($sigData);
    $md5Hash = base64_encode($md5);
    echo "ComputeCredentialHash => $md5Hash<br/>Sig Data => $sigData<br/>MD5 Sig => $md5<br/>";
    return $md5Hash;
}
```

But this does not work.  I'm sure it's due to the `ASCII.GetBytes` function, but I'm not really sure how to convert that because I'm not really sure what it does. It looks like it just returns the number of bytes, but that doesn't really make sense to me (for why it would give you something so generic to make a hash out of).  Anyway, if anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: No, it does not return the number of bytes, but the sequence of bytes that represent the text as ASCII characters. Since PHP treats every text as just a sequence of bytes internally, there should be no additional steps required. What do you get without calling mb_convert_encoding, with only plain text saved in ASCII? (And I don’t understand the parameters your method is receiving, since it does not seem to be doing anything with them.)

Comment: @CBroe The `mb_convert_encoding` actually doesn't do anything to the string it receives because it is already in ASCII. I just do that as an added measure.  But in this case it's the same going in as it is going out.  I show how the parameters are being used now, too.  That was the random string.  And yes, I had also read that about PHP and how it treats it as bytes anyway.  That's why there's nothing in there now for it, but that's the only thing I thought was different.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: it's worth pointing out that MD5 is not considered a secure algorithm for passwords (I'm guessing from the function name that this is for password hashing?).

Comment: Is your `$timestamp` that you pass into your PHP function a string already formatted as `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ` as it is explicitly done in your ASP function? If not, and it’s just a Unix Timestamp value in seconds, you have to format it to this format before embedding it into your `$sigData`.

Comment: Found this here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx saying, _“The ComputeHash methods of the MD5 class return the hash as an array of 16 bytes. Note that some MD5 implementations produce a 32-character, hexadecimal-formatted hash.”_ – PHP’s md5() does the latter, so it might be that you have to re-format its output if you want the same data structure as your ASP code generates.

Comment: @Spudley No, it's not a password.  Just a token hash from a mixture of different variables, including the current date/time.  But I cannot change how the token is generated, as this is being sent to a 3rd party.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, it is already formatted like that.  :)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, I did indeed notice that the ASP hash generated was only half the size, but was not sure how that was being done.  I had assumed it was due to the base64 encoding and that mine was just generating bad data period.  I will try to find out how to do this.  Edit - Looks like if I just do `md5($string, true);`, this will give me the raw output of 16 bytes.

Comment: @CBroe You may want to go ahead and make your MD5 catch an answer.  I'm still getting an error in my SOAP call, but it's no longer about this.  I think that was it and will mark the answer correct after I verify.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx) saying, “The ComputeHash methods of the MD5 class return the hash as an array of 16 bytes. Note that some MD5 implementations produce a 32-character, hexadecimal-formatted hash.” – PHP’s md5() does the latter, so it might be that you have to re-format its output if you want the same data structure as your ASP code generates.

Comment: Still waiting to check my hash against theirs, but I'm pretty sure this was it.  Will mark as the answer as soon as I can confirm.

Comment: I guess that only my login credentials are wrong now, so this seems to have worked.  Thanks a lot for the help.